# Wordpress Timber plugin custom routes throwing 404

Tags: wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

Timber routes throwing 404 when do curl for my custom route like below. Also GoogleBots seeing it as 404 pages.

`λ curl -I http://mysite.test/this-is-a-test/`

Results:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Fri, 23 Apr 2021 03:44:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1b PHP/7.3.8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Link: <http://mysite.test/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Although It's working fine in browser.

How can I fix this issue? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Code Example

```
Routes::map('this-is-a-test/', function ($params) {
    http_response_code(200);
    echo 'Done'; // I also tried Routes::load('test.php', $params); both shows same result
    exit;
});
```

Comment: Cann you paste some code as an example of how the route is setup?

Comment: Added code sample

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  the Routes::load method for the routing to work:

```
Routes::map('this-is-a-test/', function($params){
    Routes::load('file.php', $params, $query, 200);
});
```

See Timber [documentation](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/routing/) and dependencies, [Upstatement Routes](https://github.com/Upstatement/routes) with [AltoRouter](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter) which requires the php file path.

Comment: The result is 404 even with load method
`λ curl -I http://mysite.test/this-is-a-test/`

Comment: I have updaded my answer to make clearer and tested on a clean installation. Make sure to fast the code in your functions.php and also don't hook it to init or another action or it might be called too late